# PhpUnit - Xdebug does not stop on breakpoints in tests

Tags: symfony, phpunit, xdebug

I am using Xdebug to remote-debug a Symfony application that is running in a VM. Xdebug works without any problems when debugging HTTP requests, but I am having a problem debugging PhpUnit tests. My CLI Xdebug configuration is:

```
# /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2
xdebug.remote_log=/home/vagrant/xdebug-cli.log
```

When I run phpunit, the connection to my IDE (PhpStorm) is successfully created, and I can see that it stops on line 3 (the first executable line) of the PhpUnit PHAR, but the debugger never appears to enter my tests and does not stop on breakpoints that I place in them, even though my tests are in fact being run.

Comment: Did you set up path mapping in PhpStorm?

Comment: @fschmengler I've got path mapping set up to cover the test files, but not the PhpUnit PHAR. I'll try putting the PHAR somewhere the host system can see it and add a path mapping for it.

Comment: No luck, even with a path mapping pointing at a local copy of the phpunit PHAR file, the debugger still won't halt, either in the PHAR itself or in the test file.

Comment: What does the `/home/vagrant/xdebug-cli.log` says? In my case it shows the `file:///var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Constraint/Constraint.php` that is a default phpunit class. Keep in mind that phpunit uses reflection a lot hence it may cause the xdebug not to go deeper.

Comment: @Dimitrios You know, I didn't keep my log file from this issue I had with a project in January of 2016. Sorry.